# How do I add the password to git clone url in python script?

Tags: python, git, bitbucket

I have this small code in a python lambda that is trying to pull down a repo from bitbucket:

```
import git

def git_clone(username,password):
   new_dir = os.getcwd() + "/temp/"
   os.chdir(new_dir)

   GIT_URL = "https://{0}:{1}@bitbucket.org/test-project/test.git".format(username,password)

   git.Git(new_dir).clone(GIT_URL)
```

The git method accepts my username but does not accept my password. My password contains letters, numbers and special chars. i get this error:

```
URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Could this be a formatting issue?

Comment: try making it a raw string `r"`

Comment: Special characters in password must be URL-encoded.

Comment: i've tried ```r"``` . still no luck @rv.kvetch

Comment: how do i do that? @phd

Comment: Don't put the credentials in the URL, since that means they get written to disk.  Use a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials-environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud/#OAuthonBitbucketCloud-Cloningarepositorywithanaccesstoken) the documnetation
if using bitbucket

> git clone "https://x-token-auth:{token}@bitbucket.org/<user_name>/"

or

> url = r"https://x-token-auth:{token}@bitbucket.org/<user_name>/"

> git clone url

Here is a solution to your problem. I tested it and it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os 

def git_clone(password, username):
    if password and username:
        url_string = r"git clone https://{}:{}@bitbucket.org/{}/test.git".format(username, password, username)
        os.system(url_string)
git_clone(username="<username>", password="<password>")
```

If this solves your problem, don't forget to accept and upvote it as the correct answer

Comment: But im using bitcbucket?

Comment: I modified my answer, please see above